# pyspark.sql understanding syntax and difference between functions explode and split

Tags: split, apache-spark-sql

I am taking a [mooc](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-apache-spark-uc-berkeleyx-cs105x).

It has a shakespeareDF dataframe that has below text

```
word                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|1609                                             |
|                                                 |
|the sonnets                                      |
|                                                 |
|by william shakespeare                           |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
|1                                                |
|from fairest creatures we desire increase        |
|that thereby beautys rose might never die        |
|but as the riper should by time decease          |
|his tender heir might bear his memory            |
|but thou contracted to thine own bright eyes     |
|feedst thy lights flame with selfsubstantial fuel|
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

On it, they run below code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, explode
shakeWordsDF = (shakespeareDF.select(explode(split(shakespeareDF[0],"\s+"))
```

I would like to understand:

1. what is difference between explode and split and why do we have to
   use both? I tried to look into the online documentation and couldnt
   understand
2. why do we have to use shakespeareDF[0] and not just
   shakespeareDF

Answer (score 0):

Q.1
look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210507/explode-in-pyspark)

Q.2 
   shakespeareDF[0] -- selecting the first column

Comment: if shakespeareDF had only 1 column then do we need to use shakespeareDF[0]?

Comment: shakespeareDF is a Dataframe .. and what you need is a column.. You can select that Column by explicitly specifying column name shakespeareDF['Column_Name'] . Or using column index .. 0 in this case because that is the first(and only) column.