# Spark SQL: Parsing two correlated columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 columns in below format:

```
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|Values                                   |Flags                              |
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|0x006c,0x0072,0x0074,0x0099,0x009a,0x009f|0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01      |
|0x009a,0x00a3,0x009f,0x0099,0x00a5,0x00a7|0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00      |
```

Now I need to parse the `Flags` column, find out which position has flag set to 1 and return that corresponding value. In this case `0x009f` for both the rows.
How to do it efficiently using SQL commands? One option could be to convert the 2 columns into 2 tables and then join them by the column number? Anything better? I am not familiar with SQL much. Thanks.

Comment: check `explode` function in spark

Comment: explode function needs an array while I have a string. How to convert the values from string to array? Thanks.

Comment: `explode(split(str, ','))`.... where str is your column and `,` is separator

Comment: Thanks. I could get it to work on scala (albeit with a small change, " instead of '. For e.g. `val flattened = test.withColumn("b", explode(split($"b", ","))))`. However I need it for pyspark and this is not working. I am trying with `"df.select(explode(split(col("list"), ",")).alias("word")).show()"`. In fact I get the same error when I try the example given in [Explode in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210507/explode-in-pyspark). Error is `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`

Comment: BTW, how can I explode with 2 columns?

Comment: if you need 2 different columns then it's easy... if you need records from both column in single column you can use `concat`

Comment: I have actually got it working for 2 columns but it is in scala (Thanks to Stack Overflow). Wanted to know how to do it in python. Here is the scala code.  `val zip = udf((xs: Seq[String], ys: Seq[String]) => xs.zip(ys))
test2.withColumn("vars", explode(zip(split($"b", ","), split($"c", ",")))).select($"a",$"vars._1".alias("varA"), $"vars._2".alias("varB"))`