# Pyspark how to pivot an array column

Tags: pyspark, pivot

I have a dataset like this

```
| ID | items|
| 1| [a,b]|
| 2| [c,d]|
| 3| [e,f]|
| 4| [g,h]|
```

And I want to pivot it and obtains

```
| ID | items|
| 1| a|
| 1| b|
| 2| c|
| 2| d|
| 3| e|
| 3| f|
| 4| g|
| 4| h|
```

Do you know how I can do it ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: you want to use `explode`. see [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38210507/8279585)